# How to make multiple excel files into one file with multiple sheets dynamically with Python

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

So far I do it pretty manually:

```
df1 = pd.read_excel('/Users/user/Downloads/1.xlsx')
df2 = pd.read_excel('/Users/user/Downloads/2.xlsx')
df3 = pd.read_excel('/Users/user/Downloads/3.xlsx')
```

```
with ExcelWriter('excels.xlsx') as writer:
    df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='1')
    df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='2')
    df3.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='3')
```

But ultimately  I want to make it so I can automatically get the files pulled in from a folder and just have them become sheets. So far I have:

```
excel_names = ["1.xlsx", "2.xlsx", "3.xlsx"]
```

```
excels = [pd.ExcelFile(name) for name in excel_names]
```

But I can't figure out how to save them as multiple sheets.

Comment: This question does not show enough research effort. An efficient solution to your problem will probably involve https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's is another method using `Pathlib` which is available in python 3.4 +

this does essentially the same as anky_91's script.

the main difference is that we call the `.stem` method to name our sheets. and that we use 'glob' to find *all* excel files in your folder that match the pattern.

```
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd

folder = r'your_dir\to\excels'

excels = [f for f in Path(folder).glob('excels*.xlsx')]
# or if you want grab ALL excels 
#excels = [f for f in Path(folder).glob('*.xlsx')]

writer = pd.ExcelWriter(f'{folder}\combined_excels.xlsx',engine='openpyxl')

for wb in excels: # iterate through each excel file
    df = pd.read_excel(wb)
    df.to_excel(writer,sheet_name=wb.stem,index=False)
writer.save()
```

Comment: How would you glob if they had different names? for example: apple.xlsx, banana.xlsx'

Comment: I remember you were mentioning Pathlib, +1 :)

Comment: @anky_91 posix objects are much better than strings and easier to maintain ;) - once you try it you can never go back to `os`!

Comment: this seems it uses strings too? good thing it has a glob integrated which gives a reading flexibility, will try this too

Comment: check this out - goes over it in detail : https://realpython.com/python-pathlib/ @anky_91

Comment: I got it up and running! Thanks again all.

Comment: @JoshuaHummell you are most welcome, best of luck mate, if you need anything else let me know.

Comment: @Datanovice, I took it one step further and changed folder to say `folder = Path.cwd()`, however whenever it prints out my file it puts it just in the downloads folder. Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: @Jhumms danger here is that the script can only be ran from the location where the folder is - however, it also makes it dynamic by letting you run that script on multiple folders if you need to share it. nice addition =)

Comment: @Datanovice However whenever it prints out my file it puts it just in the downloads folder. Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205251/discussion-between-datanovice-and-jhumms).

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
```

---

```
folder=r'C:\path_to\your_folder'
path=os.path.join(folder,'excels.xlsx')
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(path, engine='openpyxl')
for i in os.listdir(folder):
    pd.read_excel(os.path.join(folder,i)).to_excel(writer, i[:-5], index=False)
    writer.save()
```

This gives a file named `excels.xlsx` in the same folder which has all files as sheetnames in a single file.